# Disply prices with two decimal zeroes as (,-) instead of (,00)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, currency

My goal is to display prices with two decimal zeroes as (`,-`) instead of (`,00`) for the Kr currency.

So far I've used the following method.

Just put this code in the theme's functions.php file:

```
function remove_zeroes_from_price($price) {
    $price = str_replace(',00', ',-', $price);
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_zeroes_from_price');
```

and it works in all places except the amount spot and checkout pages. Does anyone have another method to apply this throughout the entire website?

Comment: `except the amount spot and checkout pages` what do these pages look like ?
Do you display the prices in inputs with `type="number"` ?

Comment: can you show the price code of that two pages. how's they work?

Comment: Im using the default woocommerce and theme settings just making recommended changes from forums that i have found

[link1](http://tinyurl.com/mqgjfmm) ;

[link2](http://tinyurl.com/k2k62df)

Comment: Does anyone know what i should do to my functions.php to get this to work properly?

Comment: you should check to see if there is any other page such as woocommerce_get_total_html or simiral and see what happens there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution please see what i used below

```
function remove_zeroes_from_price($price) {
$price = str_replace(',00', ',-', $price);
return $price;}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_zeroes_from_price');
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'remove_zeroes_from_price');
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'remove_zeroes_from_price');
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'remove_zeroes_from_price');
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_zeroes_from_price');
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_contents_total', 'remove_zeroes_from_price');




// Remove all currency symbols
 function sww_remove_wc_currency_symbols( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
 $currency_symbol = '';
 return $currency_symbol;}
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'sww_remove_wc_currency_symbols',     10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html',     'remove_zeroes_from_price');
```